# User permission for remove www-data directories

Tags: linux, apache, file-permissions

my PHP aplication created directories a files under user: www-data, group: www-data.

I want to remove this directories under my linux user: *john* but I have no permission.

PHP directories are as 775 and files as 664, so group has permission to write (and that mean other users from same group can remove it or no?). I added user *john* to group *www-data* but it doesn't help.
Parent directory is www-data:www-data and 775 too.

Thank you

Comment: Correct, you will be able to delete those folders if your user is a member of that user group. however you have to re-login to actually have a session where that group membership is active.

Comment: Re-login solved it. Thank you.